# Docker - PHP script doesn't execute

Tags: php, docker

I have installed PHP (`php:7.4.2-apache`) and tried to execute script that is located in the folder where i'm working in docker:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.4.2-apache php in.php
```

File `in.php` exists, but docker prints:

```
Could not open input file: in.php
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: perhaps a full path to in.php might be in order?

Comment: Tried this one: `$ docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.4.2-apache php /usr/src/myapp/in.php`, but the same error

Comment: `-w` option sets container's working directory, so we don't need full path to script in the end

Comment: Belt and suspenders - just trying to rule out the obvious. The error seems to be coming from inside PHP and not the O/S or docker. Unless they've made some bizarre change in 7.4 you should have received a permission denied error if there was a permissions issue. So that can probably be ruled out.

Comment: Replace `php in.php` with `ls -l` and make sure the file is there with correct permissions.

Comment: It outputs `total 0`, it turns out docker doesn't move files into linux directory, and idk why

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in git bash that executes the `pwd` using `$()` command:

```
winpty docker run -it --rm -v "C:/Downloads/php-files":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.4.2-apache php in.php
```

the docs with more details: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-a-container

Comment: Are you using windows or macOs/linux? @SuperGhost

Comment: My host OS is Windows 10, php in Docker uses Linux

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in pwd? to check: `ls -la $(pwd) | grep php`  @SuperGhost

Comment: Output: `-rw-r--r-- [user and time info] in.php`

Comment: The run command works fine on my machine, could you try running it in something like git bash? What shell are you using right now? @SuperGhost

Comment: I'm using docker quickstart terminal

Comment: Could you try running it with git bash?

Comment: it outputs `the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'`, I also tried cmd, and it says `docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd): "$(pwd)" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path. See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: Very strange: `C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/src/myapp' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.`

Comment: I updated the answer, try providing the absolute path

Comment: `in.php` is located in `D:/Docker/php`, so I tried: `winpty docker run -it --rm -v "D:/Docker/php":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.4.2-apache php in.php`, but it outputs previous error with invalid working directory

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your permisions to file, because

> ... php in.php

means that you try to `Execute` the file, but you dont have [permission](https://www.zzee.com/solutions/linux-permissions.shtml) to execute it
Use [chmod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443789/what-does-chmod-x-filename-do-and-how-do-i-use-it) for that.

Comment: I noticed that Docker doesn't move files to linux, so I can't change permissions to this file in linux. I tried to change permissions to `/usr/src/myapp` folder, I also changed some permissons in windows, but nothing changed

Comment: If you're explicitly launching an interpreter (as `php in.php`) the script itself doesn't need to be executable.  If you were trying to launch it directly (`./in.php`) it would, and it would also need a line like `#!/usr/bin/env php` at the start of it.